# BLOB in queries like Insert

Tags: sql, blob, oledb

I'm working with MS Access and when I write a SQL Query if I have a string I need to put between the variable the quotation marks, and if is a object like Date, I put # between the variable. How is it for BLOB variables?

Answer (score 0):

Blob data type inserted refer this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16851/Uploading-and-Downloading-BLOBs-to-Microsoft-Acces

Comment: This confuses me... I thought that I could have a table that has many columns, and just one for the image(and they said me that the type of the column would be `LONGBINARY`). As I see in the link, I need a whole table for the picture. Can you explain me please which is the right way to store? In each link I see different things. I want to store **images** and I'm working with ASP.NET.

Comment: blob means image data type given link example

Comment: Yes, but do I need a table for the image as shown the File table? Or is it okay to just have a column LONGBINARY?